# Replace glass table top with a metal grid one to convert it to outdoor

Tags: furniture, outdoor

I have an Ikea Granas table like this one:
[image]

I don't need it anymore inside, but I was wondering if there's a way to convert it to an outdoor one. Theoretically, the table itself is glass and metal, so should work as an outdoor one well without changes, but I would like it to look like this:
[image]

I can't seem to find those metal grid table tops for sale separately to replace the glass one. 
I would like to take off those straw seats and replace with metal grid ones as well.

Is there a place I could get those metal grids? It doesn't necessarily have to be table top/chair seat by design. If I could use something that would look like one, it's ok too.

Comment: What your looking for is called _expanded metal sheet_.

Comment: I'd worry about keeping the metal tight enough and/or supported so it doesn't sag under weight -- it's going to be more flexible than the glass top was.  Personally, I'd go with your first@ thought and use it as-is, maybe with an additional layer of paint to help weatherproof it. You could even paint the underside of the glass if you want a darker top...